Non trivial closure of a set
Let
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^3-x^2 -y^2 >0\}
$$
I would like to find its closure, however I do not see a reasonable way to find it.
I first thought to relaxing the inequality
$$
B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^3-x^2-y^2\geq 0\}
$$
but here it is not easy to check that it is sufficient.
For example the point $(0,0)\in B$ but it is not in $A$ and we can show that any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ converging to $(0,0)$ fails to be in $A$ at some point (namely when the $\varepsilon$ taking is strictly less than $1$).
Thus relaxing inequality is not sufficient, and my previous argument just shows that I need to remove the point $(0,0)$.
My question is the following : is $(0,0)$ the only pathological point in my set $B$ ?
I think yes but I am not so sure to be able to prove it.
If you have some hint to provide I would be happy.
Thank you a lot !

Notice that only $y^2$ shows up. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}$, every nonnegative number is a square. So we can let $u \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}=y^2$, and just remember to reflect our solution across the $y$-axis at the end. (There is a technicality, but clearly any limit of convergent sequence of $u$s corresponds to exactly two limits of convergent sequences of $y$s, a positive one and a negative one).

@Malady Thank you for your comment ! What do you mean by only $y^2$ shows up please ?

The inequality we have only depends on the value of $y^2$; we can do a substitution to simplify things.

Also, notice that for $x\leq1$, there are no $y$-values such that $(x,y) \in A$.

One idea is to write $A$ as the union of the two regions ${0\le y < \sqrt{x^3-x^2}}$ and ${-\sqrt{x^3-x^2}< y \le 0}$

@infinitylord this is (I believe) an equivalent statement to what I said, but is a nice alternative way of looking at it.
